# OpenSuSE 10.2: create MySQL database with "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"

Tags: linux, mysql, opensuse

I have to install Wordpress on a very old OpenSuSE 10.2 web server. And for this I´m trying to create a mysql database.

Unfortunately the mysql server tells me for every attempt "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible situations:

1. `root` user hasn't a password. Try: `mysql -u root`.
2. You are using the wrong password.

   These are the steps to change the password (keep in mind that other databases and applications using this *root* user could stop working):

   Stop *mysql*.

   Start it with: `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`

   Connect using: `mysql -u root`. If you can connect then issue:

   ```
   update user set Password=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';
   flush privileges;
   exit;
   ```